# Transmitting rtsp video over webpage with JPEG compression (Eg: http://windofdubai.com/winds/webcam)

Tags: embed, rtsp, http-live-streaming

I would like to embed `.rtsp` video on a webpage with jpeg compression. Users can view the live stream without using any plugin. Live Example :  http://windofdubai.com/winds/webcam. Anyone can help please.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure this is an rtsp feed, when I look at the source to this page it looks more like mjpeg, most camera's support mjpeg and many also support rtsp. Sometimes you can have both feeds concurrently from the cameras.